# Использование конструктора в синглтоне.

Tags: c#

[Сайт_1](http://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2009/12/11075750/)
              [Сайт_2](http://skillcoding.com/Default.aspx?id=123)

Можно ли использовать конструктор при использовании синглтона для инициализации поля? и как это сделать? или инициализировать придется с помощью свойств?

Пример с сайта:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Одиночка
{
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Earth earth1 = Earth.Instance();
        Earth earth2 = Earth.Instance();

        if (earth1 == earth2)
            Console.WriteLine("одинаковы");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("не одинаковы");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
class Earth
{
    int chislo;
    private static Earth instance = new Earth();
    protected Earth()
    {
    }
    public static Earth Instance()
    {

        return instance;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так и в чём проблема? Почему бы chislo не выставить в конструкторе Earth? Просто

```
protected Earth()
{
    chislo = 999;
}
```

Или прямо при объявлении

```
int chislo = 777;
```

Если речь о том, чтобы выставить его снаружи, то да, только через свойство, а то как же иначе? Вы, конечно, можете Instance изменить так, чтобы он принимал параметр, однако, это будет весьма странно вызывать каждый раз его с параметром, который используется только один раз.